# How can I delete this border in bootstrap table?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, border, bootstrap-table

I'm using the table on bootstrap 4:

```css
#tablex {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0px;
}

#tablex tr,
th {
  padding: 1em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-9">
  <h3>last updated</h3>
  <div class="liste">
    <table class="table table-dark table-md table-responsive-md" id="tablex">
      <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Manga Adı</th>
          <th>Bölümler</th>
          <th>Yükleyen</th>
          <th>Linkler</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></td>
          <td>Deneme deneme</td>
          <td>1-56</td>
          <td>libero1i</td>
          <td>yadi.sk/bilmemne</td>
        </tr>
```

When I add `border: 0px;` I want to remove the radius as well.

[image]

How I can this?

Comment: The question need editing, please improve grammar and punctuation also read the community guide on how to write a good question. It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking at the wrong element - this border is either on a parent element of the table, or the heading on-top.

Answer (score -1):

To remove the border radii from the top of the table, set the upper left and right radii to zero: `#tablex {border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;}`

```css
#tablex {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0px;
}

#tablex tr,
th {
  padding: 1em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#tablex {
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-9">
  <h3>last updated</h3>
  <div class="liste">
    <table class="table table-dark table-md table-responsive-md" id="tablex">
      <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Manga Adı</th>
          <th>Bölümler</th>
          <th>Yükleyen</th>
          <th>Linkler</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></td>
          <td>Deneme deneme</td>
          <td>1-56</td>
          <td>libero1i</td>
          <td>yadi.sk/bilmemne</td>
        </tr>
```